# Multiplying a vector of independant gaussian r.v. by an orthogonal matrix gives independant r.v.

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, orthonormal

I found in a proof (about $\chi^2$ and Student laws) :

> Let $$\begin{pmatrix}V_1 \\ V_2 \\ ... \\ V_n \end{pmatrix} = A 
>  \begin{pmatrix}Z_1 \\ Z_2 \\ ... \\ Z_n \end{pmatrix}$$
>
> Since $Z_i$ are independent gaussian random variables and A is an
>   orthogonal matrix, the $V_i$ are independent random variables as well.

**How can we prove this, using the orthogonality of A ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $V_i$ are jointly Gaussian random variables with covariance matrix
$\hat{C} = ACA^T$ where $C$, the covariance matrix of the $Z_i$, is a
*diagonal* matrix since the $Z_i$ are given to be independent. So, if you
can show that $\hat{C}$ is also a diagonal matrix, you will have proved
that the $V_i$ are independent random variables.

Comment: Nice. This can be easily generalized to the situation where each $Z_i$ is a multi-variable Gaussian distribution with covariance matrix $\sigma_i$.