# Orthogonal Matrix and Gaussian

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, stochastic-processes

I have a related question which start with a result in Linear algebra, but I couldn't solve it. It goes like:

> If there is a non-singular matrix $K$, such that $AA^T=BB^T=K$, then show there exists an orthogonal matrix $Q$ such that $A=BQ$. This result is actually a hint for "if the component of a Gaussian vector $B$ are independent standard normal, and $A=QB$ for some orthogonal matrix $Q$, then component of $A$ are also independent standard normal."

I know that the orthogonal matrix has the property $QQ^T=I$ (identity) and it geometrically preserves the shape of a linear transformation. But I don't know how to get started.

But I feel confused how to write the proof for this. Could someone help? Thanks

Comment: The last sentence in the question, is actually "component of A".Sorry for miss

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  I have edited your question.  you can click on "edit" to see what I did - math formatting, highlighting, etc.

Comment: @antkam Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Bungo A and B are matrices.

Answer (score 1):

You can ref to this post: [probability - Multiplying a vector of independant gaussian r.v. by an orthogonal matrix gives independant r.v. - Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/632534/multiplying-a-vector-of-independant-gaussian-r-v-by-an-orthogonal-matrix-gives)

> The $V_i$ are jointly Gaussian random variables with covariance matrix $\hat{C}=ACA^T$ where $C$, the covariance matrix of the $Z_i$, is a diagonal matrix since the $Z_i$ are given to be independent. So, if you can show that $\hat{C}$ is also a diagonal matrix, you will have proved that the $V_i$ are independent random variables.

In your case, the problem is much easier to solve because $B$ is an independent **standard** Gaussian vector. This means the covariance matrix $Cov(B)$ of  $B$ is reduced to an identity matrix $I$, then the covariance of $A$ in your formula $Cov(A) = Q \ Cov(B) \ Q^T = QIQ^T = QQ^T = I$ is indeed a diagonal matrix.

This indicates that $A$ is also an independent standard Gaussian vector.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused...  Are you asking for HINT to the first part (i.e. not the part about Gaussian vector)?  If so, here it is: Simply show all the following statements in order:

- Prove that $K$ is square :) so say its size is $n \times n$.
- Prove that $K$ has full rank $n$.
- Prove that $A, B$ must be square and each must have rank $n$.
- Prove that $A, B$ are invertible.
- What is $Q$?  After this, it should be easy to prove that $Q Q^T = I$.

Comment: Hi. I am confused about how to jump from the hint to the Probability distribution part actually. So Q is like a "change of basis". But I don't get the relationship between the linear transformation and how it "preserve the Gaussian".  Thanks a lot for you help for formatting.

Comment: For the 2nd part...  that depends on what prior result you can assume.  E.g. can you use (or maybe prove) the fact that linear combinations of Gaussians are also Gaussians?  If so you can at least start with components of $A$ being Gaussians, and just need to prove they are independent and standard (i.e. mean $0$, var $1$).  Given the 1st part as hint, I would guess you need to evaluate some covariance matrix at some point...?